# How do you disable view encapsulation in a third party component in angular2/4?

Tags: css, angular, angular2viewencapsulation

I want to override the styles for an open source component I'm using, but the only way I can find to disable view encapsulation is on a component's decorator. Of course using a third party module means I can't edit the source for it. How else could it be done?

**edit**

I know about the /deep/ styles suggestion. What I'm wanting to do is override the table styles in a third party component with the styling from bootstrap 4. The custom component has a .table class applied to it, but with view encapsulation, it is unreachable by the boostrap 4 classes.

I just want to know if theres a way to blanket disable view encapsulation altogether without having to fork the code and add the component decorator property value "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" for my own use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use /deep/ css selector to override css style of nested components. For example, the component uses third party component that creates a drop down with ".dropdown" class.

The component html:

```
 <ss-multiselect-dropdown #multipleSelect
                     [settings]="settings"
                     [options]="options"
                     [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"
                     (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

and here is css of the component that override the drop down class.

```
/deep/ .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Good suggestion for a lot of purposes, but my situation is a little different. See my edit.

Comment: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None});

Comment: Update : /deep/ is deprecated as now. So maybe a different solution is required